# Configuring Mapproxy layer with non-ansi characters

Tags: mapproxy

I have a working Mapproxy 1.6.0 installation serving several WMS layers.
I am now tasked with adding an extra WMS-layer which contain the Danish character Ø.

I have defined the layer in Mapproxy.yaml like this:

```
layers:
  - name: Other-objects
    title: Other objects
    sources: ['wms_trans:Øvrige_objekter']
```

When starting Mapproxy it quits immediately with the following information in the log:

```
2015-03-11 09:42:30,322 - INFO - mapproxy.config - reading: c:\mapproxy\mapproxy.yaml
2015-03-11 09:42:30,338 - WARNING - mapproxy.config - u'wms_trans:\xd8vrige_objekter' in layers[3].sources[0] not of type str
2015-03-11 09:42:30,338 - CRITICAL - mapproxy.config - invalid configuration
```

The Ø have been translated into \xd8.
I have attempted to save mapproxy.yaml with ansi, utf8 and utf8-signature encodings, this does not seem to have an effect.

Since this is an external wms source, it is not possible to rename it.
How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

1. fix mapproxy python code and contribute (check utf-8 encoding basics : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289474/working-with-utf-8-encoding-in-python-source)
2. Create a local proxy with Nginx or Apache and rewrite the URI on the fly